# How would I use the Emmet trim filter |t (pipe t) to remove list markers?

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I have the following list;

```
* unordered item 1
* unordered item 2
* unordered item 3
```

How would I use wrap with abbreviation (`ctrl+shift+G`) or (`ctrl+shift+A`) and remove the 
`* unordered` and be left with just the item and number. I am using Sublime Text 3 on Linux 
and I select the text above then `ctrl+shift+G` Then I want to create an unordered list nav bar.
So in the wrap with abbreviation window I type `nav>ul.nav>li.nav-items$*>a|t` and the result of
this is;

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item1"><a href="">unordered item 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item2"><a href="">unordered item 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item3"><a href="">unordered item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I removed the `*` but not the `unordered`. I know the `|t` is the Emmet trim filter. Is there a
way to pass this filter a number value to tell it how many items or words to trim?
What I want to be left with after applying `|t` (the trim filter) is;

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item1"><a href="">item 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item2"><a href="">item 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item3"><a href="">item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Emmet removes only well-known list markers like numbers or bullets. It’s much better and easier to remove something else using native editor features like column selection